# Need help to troubleshoot a slow query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query that joins 2 tables `ReconCollaterlExternal` (1194994 rows) and `ReconCollateralInternal` (888060 rows).

So these are really not large tables and here is the query:

```
DECLARE @asofdate DATE = '2018-08-29';
DECLARE @threshold INT = 25

SELECT  A.* FROM (
        SELECT ri.AsOfDate, ri.Portfoliocode, SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) SumAbsEmcMtm, SUM( ABS(re.netamount)) SumAbsBrokerMtm, 
        100*(SUM( ABS(ri.netamount))- SUM( ABS(re.netamount)))/SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) PctMtmBreak 
        FROM ReconCollateralExternal ri
        INNER JOIN ReconCollateralInternal re ON re.portfoliocode = ri.portfoliocode AND  re.AsOfDate = ri.AsOfDate 
        WHERE ri.asofdate = @asofdate GROUP BY ri.portfoliocode , ri.AsOfDate  HAVING SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) != 0 
         ) A
WHERE ABS(A.PctMtmBreak) >= @threshold ORDER BY ABS(A.PctMtmBreak) DESC;
```

There are indexes on `AsOfDate`, `PortfolioCode` on both tables. The query is taking 7 seconds to run, which I think is way too long.

[image: Execution Plan]

I appreciate any help how to speed up the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Since there is appropriate index in each table we may filter them separately, then aggregate instead of sorg+join, then join aggregated values.

```
DECLARE @asofdate DATE = '2018-08-29';
DECLARE @threshold INT = 25

SELECT  
  @asofdate AsOfDate, 
  A.Portfoliocode,
  A.SumAbsEmcMtm,
  A.SumAbsBrokerMtm,
  A.PctMtmBreak 
FROM 
  (
     SELECT
        ri.Portfoliocode, ri.SumAbsEmcMtm, re.SumAbsBrokerMtm,
        100*(ri.SumAbsEmcMtm- re.SumAbsBrokerMtm)/ri.SumAbsEmcMtm PctMtmBreak 
     FROM
     (
        SELECT
           ri.portfoliocode,
           SUM(ABS(ri.netamount)) SumAbsEmcMtm
        FROM ReconCollateralExternal ri
        WHERE ri.asofdate = @asofdate 
        GROUP BY ri.portfoliocode
        HAVING SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) != 0 
     ) ri
     INNER JOIN 
     (
        SELECT
           re.portfoliocode,
           SUM(ABS(re.netamount)) SumAbsBrokerMtm
        FROM ReconCollateralInternal re
        WHERE re.asofdate = @asofdate
        GROUP BY re.portfoliocode
     ) re ON re.portfoliocode = ri.portfoliocode
  ) A
WHERE ABS(A.PctMtmBreak) >= @threshold 
ORDER BY ABS(A.PctMtmBreak) DESC;
```

give it a try.

Comment: thanks for responding. This is much much faster but produces different but may be correct result set, but who know I have to see what is the difference in logic between this and the query I posted

Comment: ok. Don't add `re.asofdate` to `GROUP BY` - you are filtering this column by single value. Result will be for sure the same without grouping by it. But server still would do some more work if it'll be kept it in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query (reformatted a bit):

```
SELECT ri.AsOfDate, ri.Portfoliocode, SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) as SumAbsEmcMtm, SUM( ABS(re.netamount)) as SumAbsBrokerMtm, 
        100*(SUM( ABS(ri.netamount))- SUM( ABS(re.netamount)))/SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) as PctMtmBreak 
FROM ReconCollateralExternal ri INNER JOIN
     ReconCollateralInternal re 
     ON re.portfoliocode = ri.portfoliocode AND re.AsOfDate = ri.AsOfDate 
WHERE ri.asofdate = @asofdate
GROUP BY ri.portfoliocode, ri.AsOfDate 
HAVING SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) <> 0 AND
       100*(SUM( ABS(ri.netamount))- SUM( ABS(re.netamount)))/SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) >= @threshold
ORDER BY PctMtmBreak DESC;
```

(The subquery doesn't affect performance.  I just removed it because it is easier for me to visualize the processing.  The use of the alias in your outer `HAVING` makes the subquery reasonable.)

Start with indexes on the `JOIN`s and `WHERE` conditions.  I would recommend:

- `ReconCollateralExternal(asofdate, portfoliocode, netamount)`
- `ReconCollateralInternal(portfoliocode, asofdate)`

I'm putting `netamount` in the first index just so the index covers the query (i.e. there are no data page lookups).

This may or may not be a big performance boost.  It depends on how much data is processed for the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff - thanks for responding. Are you suggesting composite indexes? Still taking 7 seconds :-(

Answer (score 0):

- I wonder if the `HAVING SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) != 0` kicks in early enough here, I'm guessing it does due to the order of the Compute Scalar and Filter operations going in the query plan... still, I'd rather be more explicit about it.
- As Ivan Starostin already mentioned, there is no need to `GROUP BY` on the `AsOfDate` column becauase it's a constant.
- Since the optimizer seems to prefer to use a Merge Join, we could try to avoid the 2 sorts by adding a covering index

e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON ReconCollateralExternal (AsOfDate, PortofolioCode) INCLUDE (NetAmount)
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON ReconCollateralInternal (AsOfDate, PortofolioCode) INCLUDE (NetAmount)
```

Keep in mind that there is no such thing as a free lunch: the indexes might make the query run (a bit) faster (?) but it will have a (small) performance impact on the insert/update/delete operations on the table elsewhere!

The query would then be something like this:

```
DECLARE @asofdate DATE = '2018-08-29';
DECLARE @threshold INT = 25


SELECT  Portfoliocode,
        AsOfDate = @asofdate,
        SumAbsEmcMtm,
        SumAbsBrokerMtm,
        100 * (SumAbsEmcMtm - SumAbsBrokerMtm) / SumAbsEmcMtm PctMtmBreak 

  FROM (SELECT ri.Portfoliocode, 
               SUM( ABS(ri.NetAmount)) SumAbsEmcMtm, 
               SUM( ABS(re.NetAmount)) SumAbsBrokerMtm
               -- 100 * (SUM (ABS(ri.NetAmount)) - SUM( ABS(re.netamount))) / SUM( ABS(ri.netamount)) PctMtmBreak 
          FROM ReconCollateralExternal ri
          JOIN ReconCollateralInternal re 
            ON re.PortfolioCode = ri.PortfolioCode 
           AND re.AsOfDate = @asofdate  -- ri.AsOfDate 
          WHERE ri.asofdate = @asofdate 
          GROUP BY ri.PortfolioCode 
         HAVING SUM( ABS(ri.NetAmount)) != 0 
         ) A
WHERE ABS(100 * (SumAbsEmcMtm - SumAbsBrokerMtm) / SumAbsEmcMtm ) >= @threshold 
ORDER BY ABS(100 * (SumAbsEmcMtm - SumAbsBrokerMtm) / SumAbsEmcMtm ) DESC;
```

PS: keep in mind that when you'd deploy this code on a case-senstive server it would not compile since e.g. PortofolioCode != portofoliocode

Comment: The approach by Ivan results in a hash match in the query plan, so I guess that would make it faster. I added the plan to the solution which will show up after the edit is peer reviewed.

Comment: Not sure why you would expect hash-joins to be likely faster (they're a lot of work). That said, the only way to be sure is by simply testing it out. Whether the aggregate first and join later is faster than the other way around will depend a lot on what the data looks like.